# Rendering folder contents like mod_autoindex with express and ejs in my node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have been using express and ejs to render raw html files in a `/public` folder.

For example, to render `http://localhost:3000/index.html`, I have:

```
var express = require('express');
var ejs = require('ejs');

app.engine('.html', ejs.__express);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public');  
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + './public'));
```

and can render files from `/public`:

```
% find public/
public/index.html
public/favicon.ico
public/stylesheets
public/stylesheets/style.css
public/images
public/images/banner.gif
```

I want to be able render a folder contents, like `http://localhost:3000/images/`, exactly like the Apache module mod_autoindex, a table of files as links showing the directory contents.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple, just search the npm library.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mod_autoindex will do the job.